# MDX Filling gaps

Tags: mdx, gaps-and-islands

I have a query;

```
SELECT 
[Measures].[PersonelMasrafTutarSicileGore] ON COLUMNS, 
non empty
[DimDimension2CostCenterView].[CostCenterFullName].[CostCenterFullName] *
[DimSicilBilgileri].[NAME].[NAME] * 
[DimSicilBilgileri].[SURNAME].[SURNAME] * 
[DimSicilBilgileri].[RSICILNO].[RSICILNO]*
[DimLedgerMasrafHierarchy].[GVHFMMASRAFCINSI].GVHFMMASRAFCINSI].ALLMEMBERS *
[DimLedgerMasrafHierarchy].[ACCOUNTNUM].[ACCOUNTNUM].ALLMEMBERS *
[DimDateView].[MonthOfYear].[MonthOfYear]*
[DimDateView].[MonthName].[MonthName]
ON ROWS 
FROM ( SELECT ( STRTOSET("{[DimDateView].[Year].&[2016]}", CONSTRAINED) ) ON COLUMNS 
FROM ( SELECT ( STRTOSET("{[BridgeSatisMuhasebeMM].[DimDimension2CostCenterViewKey].&[S_IHRACAT]}", CONSTRAINED) ) ON COLUMNS 
FROM ( SELECT ( STRTOSET("{[DimDateView].[MonthOfYear].&[1],[DimDateView].[MonthOfYear].&[2]}", CONSTRAINED) ) ON COLUMNS 
FROM [Model])))
```

And the results are;

[image]

which is fine. What I would like to achieve is adding gapped month values as 0. For example, selected MonthOfYear values 1 and 2. So For the first row and accountnum 760.454.02 I would like to get row for MonthOfYear 2 and with value 0. Like that, for the second row for accountnum 760.402.01 there should be 0 value for MonthOfYear 1. And if possible, if there is no values for [DimLedgerMasrafHierarchy] I would like to get 0 values for both given MonthOfYear values like;

[image]

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe just play around using `NonEmpty` and `NON EMPTY`:

```
SELECT 
[Measures].[PersonelMasrafTutarSicileGore] ON COLUMNS, 

NonEmpty(
  [DimDimension2CostCenterView].[CostCenterFullName].[CostCenterFullName]
 *[DimSicilBilgileri].[NAME].[NAME]
 *[DimSicilBilgileri].[SURNAME].[SURNAME]
 *[DimSicilBilgileri].[RSICILNO].[RSICILNO]
 *[DimLedgerMasrafHierarchy].[GVHFMMASRAFCINSI].GVHFMMASRAFCINSI].ALLMEMBERS
,[Measures].[PersonelMasrafTutarSicileGore]
)
*[DimLedgerMasrafHierarchy].[ACCOUNTNUM].[ACCOUNTNUM].ALLMEMBERS
*[DimDateView].[MonthOfYear].[MonthOfYear]
*[DimDateView].[MonthName].[MonthName]

ON ROWS 
FROM ( SELECT ( STRTOSET("{[DimDateView].[Year].&[2016]}", CONSTRAINED) ) ON COLUMNS 
FROM ( SELECT ( STRTOSET("{[BridgeSatisMuhasebeMM].[DimDimension2CostCenterViewKey].&[S_IHRACAT]}", CONSTRAINED) ) ON COLUMNS 
FROM ( SELECT ( STRTOSET("{[DimDateView].[MonthOfYear].&[1],[DimDateView].[MonthOfYear].&[2]}", CONSTRAINED) ) ON COLUMNS 
FROM [Model])));
```

I don't fully understand your comment - try just moving all hierarchies from the `[DimLedgerMasrafHierarchy]` dimension out of the `NonEmpty` function:

```
SELECT 
[Measures].[PersonelMasrafTutarSicileGore] ON COLUMNS, 

NonEmpty(
  [DimDimension2CostCenterView].[CostCenterFullName].[CostCenterFullName]
 *[DimSicilBilgileri].[NAME].[NAME]
 *[DimSicilBilgileri].[SURNAME].[SURNAME]
 *[DimSicilBilgileri].[RSICILNO].[RSICILNO]
,[Measures].[PersonelMasrafTutarSicileGore]
)
*[DimLedgerMasrafHierarchy].[GVHFMMASRAFCINSI].GVHFMMASRAFCINSI].ALLMEMBERS
*[DimLedgerMasrafHierarchy].[ACCOUNTNUM].[ACCOUNTNUM].ALLMEMBERS
*[DimDateView].[MonthOfYear].[MonthOfYear]
*[DimDateView].[MonthName].[MonthName]

ON ROWS 
FROM ( SELECT ( STRTOSET("{[DimDateView].[Year].&[2016]}", CONSTRAINED) ) ON COLUMNS 
FROM ( SELECT ( STRTOSET("{[BridgeSatisMuhasebeMM].[DimDimension2CostCenterViewKey].&[S_IHRACAT]}", CONSTRAINED) ) ON COLUMNS 
FROM ( SELECT ( STRTOSET("{[DimDateView].[MonthOfYear].&[1],[DimDateView].[MonthOfYear].&[2]}", CONSTRAINED) ) ON COLUMNS 
FROM [Model])));
```

Comment: thanks again, you saved my time once more. Your solution works like a charm for my first requirement. What about my second requirement "if there is no values for [DimLedgerMasrafHierarchy] I would like to get 0 or null values for both given MonthOfYear" which is shown last screenshot?